# error in inserting node at the end of linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I wrote this code to insert a node at the end of the `linkedlist` but I am getting only the 1st element when I am printing the list:

```
public class LinkedList {

    public class Link{

        private int data;
        private Link next;

        public Link(int data,Link next){
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public void printLink(){

            System.out.print(data);
        }

    }

    private Link head;

    public LinkedList(){
        head = null;
    }

    public void insertNode_end(int data1){

        Link node = new Link(data1,null);

        if(head == null){

            node.next = head;
            head = node;
        }

        else{
            Link ptr = head;
            while(ptr != null){
                ptr = ptr.next;
            }

            node.next = null;
            ptr = node;

        }
    }

public void printList(){
        Link curr_node = head;
        while(curr_node != null){
            curr_node.printLink();
            curr_node = curr_node.next;
        }
    }

    public static  void main(String args[]){

        LinkedList obj = new LinkedList();

        obj.insertNode_end(1);
        obj.insertNode_end(2);
        obj.insertNode_end(3);
        obj.insertNode_end(4);
        obj.insertNode_end(5);

        obj.printList();
    }

}
```

I only see `1` getting printed. I also tried to do `ptr.next = node` but then it throws `null pointer exception`.

What is the mistake I am making here?

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in the debugger in your IDE to help debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at the part when `head` is not `null`.

```
Link ptr = head;
while(ptr != null){
    ptr = ptr.next;
}
```

When this loop terminates `ptr` will be `null`. Probably not what you want it to be (I presume you want it to be the last element in the list). You probably want to change it to:

```
Link ptr = head;
while(ptr.next != null){
    ptr = ptr.next;
}
```

Note that it won't cause NPE because we know head is not null. On to the next part.

```
node.next = null;
ptr = node;
```

Now `node.next` is ok (also unnecessary since you initialized it to null in the constructor), but what is the next instruction supposed to do? It only changes the local variable. You probably meant:

```
ptr.next = node;
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't have any other issues you can consider accepting this as an answer (there's a thingie under the downvote button for that)